# Custom buttons can't be tapped Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created 5 custom buttons all in code, and they all show up perfectly; however, for some reason, there is no response when tapped like they are inactive. I have added the subviews in my ViewDidLoad and coded the constraints in a separate function that's not important I don't believe to this so let me know if that's needed to better your understanding.

The code:

```
let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

return imageView
}()

let transparentView: UIView = {
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
view.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

return view
}()


let button1: UIButton = {
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "button"), for: .normal)
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


return button
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

addSubviews()

setupViewConstraints()

}

func addSubviews() {
self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
backgroundImageView.addSubview(transparentView)
transparentView.addSubview(button1)
}

func setupViewConstraints() {

backgroundImageView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

transparentView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

 button1.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 20, paddingRight: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
  button1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}

@objc func button1Pressed() {
print("Button1 pressed")
}
```

Comment: Try to add target in viewDidLoad

Comment: can you add code of setupViewConstraints()?

Comment: @Azat I tried that but sadly didn't work

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I just updated the code and added the setupViewConstraints()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, user interaction is disabled in `UIImageView` instances. And when a superview's user interaction is disabled, its subviews can't receive the user interaction, even if you have set `button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

So add `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in `backgroundImageView` closure

```
let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()
```